# What's the best way to reuse your step definition in ruby siteprism

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

im having some issue trying to create a reusable step definition using siteprism
let say feature file is

```
Given that im on the site
Then i should see a "stack over" text
And i should see a "ask" text
And i should see a "question" text
```

then on my step definition will be

I want to have arg1 to be dynamic and this logic will check if its true

```
Then (/^i should see a "(.*?)" text$/) do |arg1|
@common_page = CommonLib.new
@ref = arg1.gsub(/\s+/,'')
expect(@common_page.*@ref*.text).to eq (arg1)
end
```

Then on my page def will be

```
class CommonLib < siteprism::page

element :stackover, "#text_header"
element :ask, "#text_ask"
element :question, "#text_question"
```

the issue im having is this **expect(@common_page.*@ref*.text).to eq (arg1)**

the mapping is wrong @ref need to use the data it got like 'stackover', 'ask' and 'question' and map in the CommonLib page def

Comment: the whole point of this one is so you can re-use your step def in different feature file

Comment: Haven't tried but I think you could use 'send' as: expect(@common_page.send(@ref).text).to eq arg1.

Comment: i have tried that one but it did not work its saying
"undefined stackover"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling #text and using the `eq` matcher is generally a bad idea since it bypasses Capybaras builtin retry behavior and can cause flaky tests on dynamically changing pages.  Instead you should use have_text or the :text option passed to the finder

```
expect(@common_page.send(@ref)).to have_text(arg1)
```

or

```
expect(@common_page.send(@ref, text: arg1)).to be
```

Also, is there a reason you've made @common_page and @ref instance variables, they seem like they should just be regular variables that go out of scope at the end of the test.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I have tested both of them they work fine. I will try to remove all the .text and eq and change them